# How to merge multiple network drives to one?

Tags: server, raid, storage

I am looking for a solution to combining multiple drives (SSD/HDD) from multiple computers to let them appear as one single drive within one computer.

Following test environment:

- server A: 3TB drive
- server B: 3TB drive
- server C: 3TB drive
- server D: local mount of the drives from server A, B, C and logical merge, so that there is one drive with 9TB

Is that possible at all?

The idea is not Hadoop or something else. I just want to be able to login to server D and go to some drive like `/mnt/mybigdrive` and be able to put a total of 9TB data into it.

I assume all the work to be done is on server D. Server A, B, C just need to be reachable over LAN and possibly SSH.

Comment: Maybe iSCSI?  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/iscsi-initiator.html

Comment: You need to frame your question more specifically around what you want to do. which system should appear as the virtual 6TB? Apache Hadoop would do what you want but would be overkill. Generally speaking you want to design your servers to either have dedicated data tasks or be clustered not simply random resources of any given server meshes together. Although... thats a cool concept.

Comment: @Terrance Looks quite promissing, but some sources indicate that this is old and not further developed. Are there more recent projects for mounting network drives to make them appear local?